# ListView shows ONLY one ImageView per item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview

I have an ListView that contains 4 ImageView but after setting the Adapter with $ ImageView I only get the first ImageView.

ListView Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onlyimageproductlist, null);
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
    }

    ImageView thumb_image1 = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.imageview_only_thumbnail_1); // thumb image
    ImageView thumb_image2 = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.imageview_only_thumbnail_2); // thumb image
    ImageView thumb_image3 = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.imageview_only_thumbnail_3); // thumb image
    ImageView thumb_image4 = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.imageview_only_thumbnail_4); // thumb image
    //building the uris...

    if (uris1 == null) {
        thumb_image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    } else {
        String[] path = uris1.split("file://");
        Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path[1], options);
        thumb_image1.setImageBitmap(map);
    }

            //same process for image 2,3,4

        return vi;
}
```

My layout :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_for_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />


            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_4"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I checked the uris and all of them refer to a picture. otherwise I will show default picture. but still I don't get any of them excet for the first thumb where I get a picture OR default picture.

Comment: When you say `//same process for image 2,3,4`, have you ensured you haven't made a copy/paste mistake and repeatedly set `thumb_image1.setImageBitmap(map);` multiple times, rather than `thumb_image2.setImageBitmap(map);`, `thumb_image3.setImageBitmap(map);`, etc

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I double checked for the binding between the view and the ressource and also for the setImage. Everything seems OK. And AFAIK we can do whatever we want on the items of the ListView, right ?

Comment: will you be able to post the complete adapter getView() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you say you are doing right in programming, then I suggest you to check your layout file as under. use weight parameter so all the ImageViews get same ratio in space.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_for_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_2"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />


            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_only_thumbnail_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had already did this, and it didn't work> But for some reason now it works. The thing is that I could see my 4 ImageView (on the graphical editor) without the weight, but on runtime I only get the first one. Anyway thank you for your quick response. NOW IT WORKS

Comment: Then if its useful, please accept and upvote so other people can take benefit of it